# Dúvida - Deixar o usuário escolher qual sera a linha a ser deletada

Tags: mysql, codeblocks, c++14

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno CRUD na linguagem C++, utilizando o MySQL c++ connector 8.0.17, e me deparei com esta dúvida:

```
void Management::excluir(){
    std::cout << std::endl << " <<<<<<<<< Excluir >>>>>>>>> " << std::endl;
    sel();
    std::cout << "Quais das opções acima voce deseja excluir: (Por ID) ";
    std::cin >> opt;
    stmt->executeUpdate("DELETE FROM produto WHERE id = " opt); // Aqui é que está a dúvida.
 //Como é que eu vou deixar o usuário escolher qual valor ele quer remover, sendo que o banco de dados não reconhece a variável opt e aqui não tem a fstrings como existe no python.
        system("clear");
        main_menu();
    }
```

O código nem compila da o seguinte error:

> error: expected ')' before 'opt'

Um exemplo onde eu utilizei algo parecido foi para selecionar o banco de dados, porém, ao invés de utilizar uma variável, eu usei uma constante e deu certo:

```
int Management::method_login(){

std::cout << "Nome de usuário: ";
std::cin >> usuario;

std::cout << "Senha: ";
std::cin >> senha;

driver = get_driver_instance();
try{
    con = driver->connect("127.0.0.1:3306", usuario, senha);
    if(!con->isClosed()){
        std::cout << "Conexão realizada com sucesso!" << std::endl;
        con->setSchema(DATABASE);
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        stmt->execute("USE " DATABASE); // Nesta linha, DATABASE no caso é a constante.
        std::cout << "Banco de dados: << " << DATABASE << " >> selecionado com exito!" << std::endl;
        main_menu();
    }
}catch(sql::SQLException){
    std::cout << "Conexão não sucedida!" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Para fazer algo parecido, eu precisaria utilizar uma constante, mas, em uma breve pesquisa no Google eu percebi que constantes são imutáveis então não tem como eu utiliza-las, como no primeiro trecho de código, no contexto onde eu necessito que o usuário decida qual valor sera excluído.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o meu problema lendo a documentação [aqui](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-cpp-1.1-en.a4.pdf), Veja no link fornecido por " aqui ", pois o do site oficial esta cortado grande parte das informações.

```
Management Management::adicionar(){
    std::string produto;
    float preco;
    std::cout << "Digite o nome do produto: ";
    std::cin >> produto;
    std::cout << "Digite o preço do produto: ";
    std::cin >> preco;

    pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO produto (nome, preco) VALUES (?, ?)");
    pstmt->setString(1, produto);
    pstmt->setDouble(2, preco);
    pstmt->execute();

    delete pstmt;
    system("clear");
    return main_menu();

}
```